# Bounding the $L^q$ norm of the Fourier inversion

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

Given $N>1$, and $\psi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $0 \leq \psi \leq 1$, which is radial and satisfies:
$$ \begin{cases} 
      \psi = 1 & \text{ on }\frac{3}{4}\leq |\xi| \leq \frac{5}4{} \\
      \psi = 0 & \text{ on }|\xi| \leq \frac{1}{2} \text{ and on } |\xi| \geq 2 
   \end{cases}
$$
We note that $\psi$ defined in this way is a smooth approximation of the characteristic function of the annulus $\frac{3}{4} \leq |\xi| \leq \frac{5}{4}$. For the $\psi$ defined above, we define an operator $P_N$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ by:
$$(P_Nf)(\xi) = (K_N * f)(\xi)$$
where
$$K_N(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big[\psi\Big(\frac{x}{N}\Big)\Big] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{2\pi i x \cdot \zeta}\psi\Big( \frac{\zeta}{N}\Big) d\zeta $$
I need to show that all $1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty$,
$$||P_N f||_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)} \leq CN^{\frac{d}{p}-\frac{d}{q}}||f||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}$$

So far, I have: Recall Young's convolution inequality which  states that for $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $g \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $\frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{r} - 1$ with $1 \leq p,q,r\leq \infty$, we have
$$||f*g||_q \leq ||f||_p ||g||_r$$
Now, we know that $P_Nf = K_N * f$. Then, we have that
$$||P_N f||_q  = ||K_N *f ||_q  = ||f* K_N||_q \leq  ||f||_p ||K_N||_r$$
Consider $||K_N||_r$. By definition,
$$K_N(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot x}\psi\Big( \frac{x}{N}\Big) dx = N^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot (Nu)}\psi (u) du$$
$$\Rightarrow ||K_N||_r = N^d \cdot C(r,\xi)$$
where
$$C(r,\xi) = \Big| \Big|  \int_{\frac{1}{2}\leq |u|\leq \frac{3}{4}}e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot (Nu)} \psi( u ) du + \int_{\frac{3}{4} \leq |u|\leq \frac{5}{4}}e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot (Nu)} du + \int_{\frac{5}{4} \leq |u| \leq 2}e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot (Nu)}\psi (u) du\Big|\Big|_r$$

Where can I go from here?

Comment: One should have $||K_N(\xi)||_r = N^{d/r}C(r,\xi)$ instead of $||K_N(\xi)||_r = N^{d}C(r,\xi)$ and with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{r} + 1$ so $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} -1 = \frac{1}{r}$ we get $N^{\frac{d}{r}}C(r,\xi) = N^{\frac{d}{p}+ \frac{d}{q} - d}C(r,\xi) = N^{\frac{d}{p} + d\frac{1 - q}{q}}$.